# Trying to create Typescript definition for NodeJS module

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a Typescript definition for the NodeJS formidable module that I want to use to upload files to the server. But that throws an error. The typescript compiler does not compile the statement "import formidable = require('formidable');" to its javascript equivalent. I need to know if the formidable definition is correct.

Here's the upload.ts which contains the file parse code:

```
import fs = require('fs');
import path = require('path');
import formidable = require('formidable');
var formidable = new formidable.Formidable();
```

Here's the upload.js which is created by the typescript compiler:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var formidable = new formidable.Formidable();
```

The typescript compiler is not creating a require statement for the formidable module. this needs to be fixed.

Here's the typescript definition file:

```
/// <reference path="../Main.d.ts" />

declare module "formidable" {
    export interface Formidable {
        IncomingForm(): Formidable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what's going on:

Because your `Formidable` module doesn't contain any *values* (vars, classes, or modules containing vars or classes), it doesn't create a name in the "value space" (Typescript has three different namespaces - types, values, and namespaces).

When you `import` something, you get "all meanings" of the imported value. In this case, because there is no value in the `Formidable` module, the import does not create any object called `formidable` in the value space.

Then you do this:

```
import formidable = require('formidable');
var formidable = new formidable.Formidable();
```

When resolving the expression `new formidable.Formidable()`, the compiler looks for a value called `formidable`. It finds one - the `var` you just created (don't have vars with the same name as imports - this wouldn't work in JavaScript code either...). Because the variable is used in its own initializer, type inference just resorts to `any`.

Essentially what you've done is this:

```
var x = new x.y(); // ??
```

Going back to the root problem, your definition file for `Formidable` needs to include some value. It should probably look like this (with a class instead of an interface):

```
declare module "formidable" {
    export class Formidable {
        IncomingForm(): Formidable;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really thorough answer!

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Thats a very helpful answer. However, my code is not solved due to another error. Can you please take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603247/unable-to-import-nodejs-module-into-typescript-code