# Unable to import NodeJS module into Typescript code

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a NodeJS + ExpressJS which I am migrating to Typescript. I am using a Node module "Formidable" for which I am trying to create a typescript definition. However, I'm not able to import the module elements into Typescript code due to an error:

Here;s the module definition:

```
/// <reference path="../Main.d.ts" />

declare module "formidable" {
    export class Formidable {
        constructor();
        IncomingForm() : Form;
    }

    export class Form{
        encoding : String;
        uploadDir : String;
        keepExtensions : Boolean;
        type : String;
        parse(String, Function) : void;
    }

}
```

Here's the file "Upload.ts" that imports the module

```
import fs = require('fs');
import path = require('path');
import formidableModule = require('formidable');
var formidable = new formidableModule.Formidable();
```

Here's "Upload.js" created by the Typescript compiler

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var formidableModule = require('formidable');
var formidable = new formidableModule.Formidable();
```

Here's the error

```
C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\Core\lib\Upload.js:5
var formidable = new formidableModule.Formidable();
                 ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anjan\WebstormProjects\Core\lib\Upload.js:5:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anjan\WebstormProjects\Core\app.js:9:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

Process finished with exit code 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `ts` but this is how I export entire classes (I had this same problem)

```
module.exports.formidable = {
    method1: function(req){
        /// code here
    },
    method2: function(param1, param2) {
            ///code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do it in NodeJS without TS - which works fine with me any ways. However, because I'm migrating to TS, I'm trying to figure how to do it in TS.

Answer (score 0):

I think your definition for Formidible is incorrect.

Basically you are getting undefined on `Formidable` class I don't see that in the docs https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable#api

Perhaps https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable#formidableincomingform :

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
```